# symfony 2 equivalent for url_for() function in symfony 1

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, symfony

In Symfony 1 we can access an action in template page as for example `url_for('modulename/actionname')` without writing anything in routing.yml.

how is this possible in Symfony2?,that is if i have to access more than one action in a twig without specifying in routing.this is useful while using ajax.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how you can generate a url by passing a module name and action name, instead of a route name. Is that right?

I don't think this is possible in Symfony2. If you take a look at the `generate` method in `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator` you'll see that it expects a route's name as the first parameter. Also, Symfony2 doesn't natively support the generic routes that symfony 1 does (shown below for reference).

```
default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Without these generic routes, you can't simply access /myModule/myAction without actually defining a route for it. And don't forget that Symfony2 now uses bundles, which would complicate this further.

So for whatever actions you want to access, you'll need to write routes for them.

In order to actually generate the URLs...
- From a controller: `$this->generateUrl($routeName);`
- From a PHP template: `$view['router']->generate($routeName);`
- From a Twig template: `{{ path('_routeName') }}` or `{{ url('_routeName') }}` for an absolute URL

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [Arms' words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005972/symfony-2-equivalent-for-url-for-function-in-symfony-1/16871412#8011300), here are few examples (with parameters):

Let's say our routing is:

```
#routing.yml
acme_demo_page:
  path: /{page}.{_format}
  defaults:
    _controller:  AcmeDemoBundle:Page:index
```

We'll generate the URL for this routing, as follows:

**From any controller's action:**

```
$url = $view['router']->generate("acme_demo_page", array(
    "page" => "main",
    "_format" => "html",
));
```

**From any PHP template:**

```
$url = $this->generateUrl("acme_demo_page", array(
    "page" => "main",
    "_format" => "html",
));
```

**From any Twig template:**

```
<a href="{{ path('acme_demo_page', {page:'main', _format:'html'}) }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ url('acme_demo_page', {page:'main', _format:'html'}) }}">Abs Home</a>
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers.